# Why is "uncanny" not the opposite of "canny"?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

If [**canny**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/canny) means "cunning"

> Having or showing shrewdness and good judgement, especially in money or business matters.

why does [**uncanny**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/uncanny) mean "supernatural"?

> Strange or mysterious, especially in an unsettling way.

*Uncanny* should have meant "slow-witted" or "foolish" which is the opposite of *cunning*.

Comment: "Simple" is not the opposite of "cunning", it's the opposite of "complicated" or "difficult", so I had to change that bit in your question. Please feel free to rollback if you dislike my suggestions or edit.

Comment: Perhaps there's a link to [ken](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/ken).

Comment: _Canny_ also means ‘pleasant, nice’, by which definition _uncanny_ is closer to being an antonym—although that is fairly coincidental, given that the original meaning of _uncanny_ was an antonym to the meaning of _canny_ that you quote here.

Comment: _"Strange or mysterious, especially in an unsettling way."_ is not the same as "supernatural". The supernatural is often portrayed in an uncanny way, but that does not make everything that's uncanny inherently supernatural. (e.g. every soldier being portrayed wielding a rifle, does not make everyone who wields a rifle automatically also a soldier)

Comment: Please include the research you’ve done. Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.

Comment: It is not good to pose questions in terms of "Why is it the case that...". It suggests that English responds, or should respond, to the laws of logic. And as we all know modern English, being the product of over 1,000 years of  history, can be logical, but it often isn't. That does not mean that the question you ask is not an interesting or worthwhile one. It just needs to be phrased differently e.g. "What is the etymological relationship, if any, between *canny* and *uncanny*?"

Answer (score 3):

***[Uncanny](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=uncanny):***

> - 1590s, "mischievous;" ***1773 in the sense of "associated with the supernatural," originally Scottish and northern English, from un- (1) "not" + canny***.
> - Canny is from the Anglo-Saxon root ken: "knowledge, understanding, or cognizance; mental perception: an idea beyond one's ken." ***Thus the [uncanny](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncanny) is something outside one's familiar knowledge or perceptions.***

(Etymonline, Wikipedia)

Also from  [The Word Detective](http://www.word-detective.com/2009/01/cannyuncanny/):

> - “Canny” is a very cool word. It first appeared in Scots and Northern English dialects as an adjective meaning “knowing, judicious, prudent, cautious,” and is simply based on the verb “can” in the sense of “to be able” (as in “I can fly”). ***“Canny” was picked up by English writers in the 17th century, who applied it to the Scots themselves in the sense of “cunning,” “wily” or “thrifty,” in line with the English portrayal of Scots as clever and frugal. The sense of “sharp” and “shrewd” eventually became more generalized, and today we use “canny” to mean “perceptive and wise” (“The canny investor avoids market fads”)***.
> - One of the other meanings of “canny” back in Scotland in the 16th century, however, was “trustworthy,” and when “uncanny” first appeared it was in the sense of “malicious or incautious” (i.e., not trustworthy). ***By the 18th century, “uncanny” had come to mean specifically “not safe to trust because of connections to the supernatural,” and eventually the word took on its modern meaning of “supernatural,” “weird” and “strange.” So “uncanny” came to mean something quite different than simply “not smart.”***

Comment: One of the Scots meaning is 'canny' is 'Favourable; fortunate, lucky, of good omen, esp. in a superstitious sense.' http://www.dsl.ac.uk/entry/snd/canny

Comment: Can you explain how this answers the OP's question of 'why'?

Comment: @Mitch - well, tell me how and why it does not!

Comment: Josh, all your answer does is cut and paste describing the two two word. You don't add anything that explains why they are not exact opposites as might be expected due to the prefix. It is what the OP is asking.

Comment: @Mitch - The sense of uncanny meaning “supernatural” and how it devepolled is well explained in the sources  I cite. I don’t see how that doesn’t answe the question.

Comment: Basically, they started out as opposites and their usages drifted.